# Что лучше использовать для отрисовки графиков на wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Будут поступать данные с com порта. И нужно будет эти данные показать в виде графика, которая через каждые (допустим 10 сек) будет меняться, т.к поступают новые данные. Теперь вопрос, что лучше использовать для отрисовки графиков на wpf?
И второе, в winforms я использовал zedgraph, можно ли его использовать с wpf, или лучше не стоит, если да то можно пример небольшой, не могу ни чего найти на эту тему в интернете.

Comment: Была та же самая проблема, я ничего не нашел - пришлось свой контрол писать для этого. Есть куча библиотек красивых для WPF но они платные :( А стандартного нету ничего. Можно написать свой контрол у которого будет метод "обновить данные" и его использовать

Answer (score 3):

Зачем так сложно? Вполне достаточно прямых рук и [`Polyline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример: вот такой XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleGraph.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Function Graph" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Polyline Name="Graph" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

и code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SizeChanged += UpdateGraph;
    }

    double func(double x) => // should be injected from VM
        Math.Sin(x);

    double minX = -2 * Math.PI; // should be injected from VM
    double maxX = 2 * Math.PI; // should be injected from VM

    double minY = -1.5; // should be injected from VM
    double maxY = 1.5; // should be injected from VM

    void UpdateGraph(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pixelWidth = Graph.ActualWidth;
        var pixelHeight = Graph.ActualHeight;
        PointCollection points = new PointCollection((int)pixelWidth + 1);
        for (int pixelX = 0; pixelX < pixelWidth; pixelX++)
        {
            var x = MapFromPixel(pixelX, pixelWidth, minX, maxX);
            var y = func(x);
            var pixelY = pixelHeight - MapToPixel(y, minY, maxY, pixelHeight);
            points.Add(new Point(pixelX, pixelY));
        }
        Graph.Points = points;
    }

    double MapFromPixel(double pixelV, double pixelMax, double minV, double maxV) =>
        minV + (pixelV / pixelMax) * (maxX - minX);

    double MapToPixel(double v, double minV, double maxV, double pixelMax) =>
        (v - minV) / (maxV - minV) * pixelMax;
}
```

выдаёт следующий график:

[image: график, что ж ещё]

Comment: А сетку? Просто линиями расчертить?

Comment: @MaximK: Ну да. И стрелки. В любом случае сторонние контролы делают то же самое (только их настроить может быть сложнее, чем написать вручную).

Comment: double func(double x) => Math.Sin(x);
не пойму почему выдает ошибку...

Comment: @MaximK: А какая у вас версия Студии?

Comment: VS 2013 express

Comment: А, понятно, это синтаксис для 2015. Для 2013 пишите просто `double func(double x) { return Math.Sin(x); }`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [Modern UI Charts](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] или [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Если при использовании ModernUI удалить обновление всех стилей - работает очень даже шустро.
Toolkit - выглядит старовато, но работает отменно!