# Организация UI в приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, Господа. Мне нужно написать небольшое приложение, которое будет представлять примерно вот такой интерфейс:
[image: Прототип UI]
На рисунке изображено 3 вида UI, которое должно иметь окно при маштабировании(скорее всего колесиком мыши).

Таблица представляет из себя календарь, где также при маштабировании должны отображаться соответственно часы, дни, месяцы, года.
Цветные полоски имеют размер, который соответствует промежутку времени. Они должны быть функциональными, я могу их двигать, переставлять местами, и накладывать один на другой, как это видно на рисунке(желтая полоска). Они несут некоторую информацию, поэтому я должен буду получать ее, скорее всего при наведении мыши.

На вооружение взял WPF + C#. Использовать буду MVVM

Меня интересует, как сделать такую таблицу? Есть контрол DataGrid, который может представлять данные в табличной форме. Но дело в том, что:
1. Здесь будет неограниченное количество столбцов, которые будут изменяться при маштабировании, как я уже сказал - при приближении года будут переходить в месяцы, месяцы в дни, дни в часы.
2. Цветные полоски могут переходить из одного столбца в другой, перетаскиваться мышкой и тд. Поэтому DataGrid точно не подходит в этом случае.

У меня вопрос только в том, с чего начать пользовательский интерфейс? Может есть уже готовые решения такого подхода? Единственное, где я видел такой UI, так это в приложениях по созданию музыки - Cubase, Abliton и другие.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Можно использовать Grid.

Comment: DataGrid хорошо подходит только для прямого отображения таблицы в UI (что практически всегда нехорошо, за исключением бухгалтерских программ). А почему бы не создавать UI в code-behind руками, подписавшись на изменение зума? Очевидно, zoom level не является свойством VM.

Comment: @VladD, в плане создавать UI в code-behind? Так, я наверное не все сказал. Количество строк, у меня на рисунке, равно двум, но может быть больше. Это величина не постоянная

Comment: Ну например так, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532565/10105

Comment: Я имею в виду, что если UI сложный, и нетривиальным образом зависит от UI-параметров, ну так лучше не пытаться работать с конвертерами, а [пере]создавать его вручную из code behind.

Comment: @VladD, так, ну это понятно. Это при изменение зума, мне нужно будет в code-behind изменять соответственно столбцы, и увеличивать/уменьшать полоски. А как полоски располагать размером, соответствующим времени? Их еще можно будет двигать

Comment: Думаю вам подойдёт канвас + трансформации. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777205/218063

Comment: @Bretbas: Ну, ты ж как-то рассчитывал их начальное положение? Вот точно так же нужно его перерассчитать, тем же кодом.

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, вроде понятно. Сетку мне нужно тоже в Canvas'е рисовать ручками?

Comment: Ну да, для начала ручками, потом уже видно будет

Comment: На мой взгляд надо сделать свой `Custom Control` - "Растягиваемая цветная полоска", которая должна уметь масштабироваться. Затем уже на базе этого контрола можно собирать по кирпичикам остальной интерфейс, но начинать нужно с него.

Comment: @Bulson ну хорошо, я начну если с этого, научу этот контрол растягиваться при маштабе. Но он должен на чем нибудь находится. Должна быть какая то поверхность для него

Comment: Неа, масштабироваться у вас будет все автоматически с помощью трансформаций

Comment: Вам нужно сделать наследника канваса с сеткой и использовать его в качестве панели для ItemsControl, дальше все как в указанном мною примере

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну допустим я сделал наследника Canvas с сеткой. Трансформации Вы применяете на ItemsControl, но этот наследник Canvas'а должен знать как при изменении трансформации( тоесть зума ), изменять свою сетку!

Comment: Масштабирование должно быть "фиктивным", т.е. это просто переключение из одного режима отображения на другой, смена состояний отрисовки, так сказать. Сделать 3-4 заранее готовых режимов отрисовки контрола и преключаться между ними последовательно по команде прокрутки.

Comment: @Bretbas, сетка будет сама масштабироваться, как и любое содержимое канваса

Comment: @Bulson, разве?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Вы понимаете, что я имею ввиду под "маштабированием" сетки? Должны года в месяца переходить, месяца в дни, дни в часы. Понимаете? На сколько я знаю, это TimeBar. В интернете они платные. Тоесть при увеличение/уменьшении зума, должна полностью перерисовываться сетка. А значит, на сколько я понимаю, это должно быть отлажено в самом наследнике Canvas'а